# Unit Quaternions on the 3-sphere, $S^3$ as orthogonal transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations, quaternions

I am reading through Andrew Hanson's "Visualizing Quaternions" and came across this passage on page 50:

> $q(\theta, {\bf n}) = \left( \cos\frac{\theta}{2}, {\bf n} \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \right)$ produces the standard rotation matrix ${\bf R} \left( \theta, {\bf n} \right)$ for a rotation by $\theta$ in the plane perpendicular to ${\bf n}$, where ${\bf n} \cdot {\bf n} = 1$. $\theta$ is an angle obeying $0 \leq \theta < 4 \pi$ rather than $0 \leq \theta < 2 \pi$. *This extension of the range of $\theta$ allows the values of q to reach all points of the hypersphere $S^3$.*

Here, $q$ represents the quaternion and ${\bf n}$ the rotation axis.

To describe how I visualize $S^3$, I will first describe analogously how to visualize $S^2$. Imagine cross sections of $S^2$ as we pass from $z = 1$ to $z = -1$. The cross sections are circles of radius $\sin\beta$, where $0 \leq \beta \leq \pi$ is the usual polar angle in the spherical polar parametrization of $S^2$. If $0 \leq \alpha < 2\pi$ is the azimuth, then $\alpha$ gives a parametrization of every cross sectional circle.

Now, to visualize $S^3$, I draw a set of 2-spheres, the intersections of $S^3$ with the various hyperplanes $w$ = constant, where we pass from $w = 1$ at the North Pole through the equator at $w = 0$, to the South Pole at $w = -1$. $w$ represents the real part of the quaternion. In this case, we identify $w = \cos \frac{\theta}{2}$. The North Pole and the South Pole are degenerate 2-spheres of zero radius. $\sin \frac{\theta}{2}$ represents the radius of every cross sectional 2-sphere. When $\theta = \pi$, $w = 0$, and we are at the equator of $S^3$, and the radius is unity.

Here is my concern: I see no reason for extending the range of $\theta$ to cover all the points on $S^3$. $0 \leq \theta < 2 \pi$, allows us to reach every point on $S^3$, with ${\bf n}$ being a unit vector.

Is this an error on the part of Hanson?

Comment: As I understand it, by *"hypersphere"* Hanson refers to all unit quaternions, not $S^3$. The reason for the extension, I believe, is that $q(\theta, \mathbf{n})$ and $q(-\theta,-\mathbf{n})$ refer to the exact same rotation, and extending the $\theta$ range covers them both for the same $\mathbf{n}$.

Comment: But the set of all unit quaternions is one-to-one with points on $S^3$. Besides, Hanson says in the passage the the extension of $\theta$ is required to reach all points on $S^3$.

Comment: Oops, apologies. Once again, I forgot $S^N$ refers to the surface of the $N+1$-dimensional hypersphere, not the $N$-dimensional one. Anyway, I concur with [arctic tern](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2340065/318422)'s answer; that the extension is necessary (only) for a fixed $\mathbf{n}$ to cover $S^3$.

Comment: @NominalAnimal The extension is necessary to cover a copy of $S^1$ in $S^3$ for fixed $\bf n$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it *has* two answers and OP just disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessary to make $\theta$ range over the interval $[0,4\pi)$ in order to cover all of $S^3$. On the other hand, when you mentally picture rotations around an axis as an animation, you are essentially visualizing a one-parameter subgroup, and for a *fixed* axis $\mathbf{n}$ in order to parametrize the entire subgroup from the identity and back to itself (in exactly one trip) while we only need $\theta$ to range in $[0,2\pi)$ if we are in the rotation group $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, we need $\theta$ to range in $[0,4\pi)$ if we are in the spin group $\mathrm{Spin}(3)=S^3$ that double covers it. This is likely the explanation for the mixup.

Take $\mathbb{R}^2$ for a simpler example. If you parametrize the double cover of the unit circle (which is again just the unit circle) via $(\cos(\theta/2),\mathbf{n}\sin(\theta/2))$ where $\mathbf{n}\in\{\pm i\}$ we only need $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, but in order to parametrize the whole circle group $\mathrm{Spin}(2)$ for a fixed choice $\mathbf{n}=+i$ we need to use the double-size interval $[0,4\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec u\in S^2$ be a unit vector and $\phi\in[0,4\pi)$. Then
$$(\cos(\tfrac{4\pi-\phi}2),\sin(\tfrac{4\pi-\phi}2)\vec u)=
(\cos(\tfrac{\phi}2),\sin(\tfrac{\phi}2)(-\vec u))$$
as [unit quaternions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).

So, it is enough to take $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ in the representation
$$q=(\cos\tfrac\theta 2,\sin\tfrac\theta 2\vec u)\in S^3$$
of a unit quaternion.

Answer (score -1):

It’s interesting that you adopted the “extending the range of $\theta$” wording, so apparently you didn’t take issue with the idea that the usual range for rotation angles is $0\le\theta\le2\pi$. But your argument would also show that rotation angles in $SO(3)$ don’t need to go up to $2\pi$; every rotation can be reached with $0\le\theta\le\pi$. We usually think of rotations parametrized by a rotation angle between $0$ and $2\pi$, even though this yields two different parametrizations for the same rotation if we flip both the axis and the angle, because it allows the entire $U(1)$ subgroup of rotations around one axis to be described with one axis and not two. Analogously, it makes sense to think of unit quaternions as parametrized by an angle between $0$ and $4\pi$ so that the range of the angle corresponds to a $U(1)$ subgroup.